# PhpStorm No Usages for get Attribute

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I'm using the latest version of PhpStorm (2022.3.1) and Laravel 9+. This is not a huge issue, but rather a major eyesore.

For some reason when I use a Model to create a custom Attribute like this:

```
    public function getFormattedStartDateAttribute(): string
    {
        if (!$this->start_date) {
            return 'TBD';
        } else {
            return $this->start_date->format('M. d, Y');
        }
    }
```

And use in the view like this or this:

- Date `{{ $event->formattedStartDate }}`
- Date `{{ $event->formatted_start_date }}`

PhpStorm still says the method has `no usages`?

Image:
[image]

Is there a way to fix this? I've tried reindexing my project. This is a new feature called [Code Vision](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/#user-experience).

Comment: Sounds like you should open an issue in that plugin's issue tracker. PhpStorm itself can't know that any occurence in a Blade template leads to a call of that function. Also, did you set any typehint for the model within the template?

Comment: *"And use in the view like this or this:"* PhpStorm is correct here -- there is no **explicit / direct** usage of `getFormattedStartDateAttribut()` method. This method is called under the hood by Laravel. And PhpStorm does not provide any Laravel-specific functionality. If anything, it is provided by Laravel specific plugin (like Laravel Idea). So you better contact plugin author about it, what he can do to let PhpStorm know that calling `$event->formatted_start_date` is actually an indirect usage of `getFormattedStartDateAttribute()` method.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help. I will contact the Author of the Plugin.

Comment: Actually I don't think it's coming from Laravel Idea plugin. I disabled it and the usage data is still showing. I'll contact PhpStorm I guess.

Comment: "and the usage data is still showing" - what do you mean by that? "No usages" is part of PhpStorm's latest feature Code Vision

Comment: *"Actually I don't think it's coming from Laravel Idea plugin. I disabled it and the usage data is still showing."* Of course. Because it's PhpStorm core functionality. BUT the link/reference between `formatted_start_date` and `getFormattedStartDateAttribute()` should be established/provided by something (a plugin???) that KNOWS how **Laravel framework works** under the hood. And since PhpStorm does NOT provide any Laravel-specific functionality... it cannot do that and correctly writes "no sages". Period.

Comment: @NicoHaase Showing the usage of a method is part of PhpStroms latest release. Called "Code vision for PHP". I thought it might have belonged to that plugin Laravel Idea.

So when I say, "Usage data is not showing" I mean the there should be a "1 usage" above the getFormattedStartDateAttribute() method since I'm using it in the view.

Comment: @LazyOne Then why does it show the usages when I do this? `public function isGuest(): bool { return $this->participant_parent_id !== null; }` 

Does code view not work with Attributes?

When I use `{{ $participant->isGuest() }}` in the view, It shows I'm using this 3 times in my code.

Comment: @daugaard47 Please, try to re-read comments that me an Nico Haase wrote -- the part where the "reference" info comes from. If the IDE does NOT know that calling `$event->formatted_start_date` actually makes a HIDDEN call to `getFormattedStartDateAttribute()`  under the hood, then HOW should it write "1 usage"? It should have this knowledge from somewhere, right?

Comment: @daugaard47 Regarding `isGuest()` -- based on your example the usage is direct and  **explicit** here -- `$participant->isGuest()`.

Comment: @LazyOne Okay I understand what you are saying now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is very easy to solve, you can use [`barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) and then run `php artisan ide:model`, that will go over the models and create a PHPDoc block (you can add options and create them in the same model file or in a new file where you only have this PHPDock blocks), and PHPStorm will read this doc block and know when you are calling `attributeWhatever` is what type.

It will add this in your case:

```php
/**
 * @property string $formattedStartDate
 */
```

This way, any IDE that is capable of understanding PHPDock blocks, will understand that when you do `$class->formattedStartDate`, you are refering to that one, and it is of type `string`.

BUT, no IDE (unless using a plugin that I am not aware of) will understand that `getFormattedStartDateAttribute` -> `formattedStartDate`, so you will still get `no usages` for `getFormattedStartDateAttribute`, but at least you can track `formattedStartDate` and do whatever you want with it.

---

One quick tip, if you are using Laravel 9+, please change that code from:

```
public function getFormattedStartDateAttribute(): string
{
    if (!$this->start_date) {
        return 'TBD';
    } else {
        return $this->start_date->format('M. d, Y');
    }
}
```

To:

```php
public function formattedStartDate(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute
{
    return Attribute::get(
        function ($value, $attributes) {
            if (! $attributes['start_date']) {
                return 'TBD';
            } else {
                return $attributes['start_date']->format('M. d, Y');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Why? Because using `getFormattedStartDateAttribute` is the old way, Laravel 9+ made it easier, read about [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).

See that `getXXXXAttribute` and `setXXXXAttribute` is not even present on the documentation anymore.